# How can a server subscribe to a collection from the client?

Tags: meteor

I was wondering if it is possible that a server can subscribe to a collection from the clients so that only the server got everything and the users only have their local copy of the data.

I would like to create a meteor (mobile) app where people can create some content and store it in a collection (only local on the device) that noone can see except the "owner" itself locally and the server who owns everything. If a local collection is created the server subscribes to that collection so the server can collect all the data from every user and show it e.g. on a website. So I have 3 Components. The mobile app that generates the content (clients), the server that collects everything, and a website that only read the db with the complete content.

so,
is it possible that a server can subscribe to every collection from every user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have some kind of authentication (or if you use the Accounts Meteor package) you can use `Meteor.publish()`on server side to only publish what belongs to the current user.

For example:

```
//Common Collection for both client and server (declared in lib/ for example): 
//(will be a full DB on the server and a minimongo with published data only 
//on the client)
Data = new Mongo.Collection('Data');    

//Server: (publish to client only what belongs to the user)
Meteor.publish('userData', function(){
    return Data.find({your_user_id_field:this.userId});
});

//Client: (the client only gets the data that belongs to him/her)
Meteor.subscribe('userData');
[... use the local collection as usual ...]
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but the idea is: every subscribed user (client) is allowed to see his data. Have a look at the `collection.allow(options)` documentation. A client subscribes to a collection and the server decides what the client can see.

Comment: ah ok this makes more sense I see. so the server allows every user to create stuff in a subscribed "user_content" collection on the server and only allows the user to see/edit its own stuff. So the server owns everything and the users only see their own stuff.

Comment: Yes, correct. All the (client) data is at the server (makes sense). The server decides which client can see which part of the data.